# Query ElasticSearch on Node.js with HTTP module Ignores Request Body

Tags: node.js, http, elasticsearch

StackOverflow community. I've started to play with ES and Node.js, and right now I'm trying to query my ES instance using the HTTP module.

I'm trying to mimic the following curl GET request:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "this is a test", 
      "fields": [ "subject", "message" ] 
    }
  }
}
'
```

like this:

```
var options = {
  hostname: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 9200,
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/twitter/tweet/_search?pretty',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'accept': 'application/json'
  },
  json: query
  body: {
          "query": {
            "multi_match" : {
              "query":    "this is a test", 
                "fields": [ "subject", "message" ] 
            }
          }
        }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (response) {
var responseBody = "";

    response.setEncoding("UTF-8");

    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        responseBody += chunk;
    });

    response.on("end", function() {
        fs.writeFile("responseBody.json", responseBody, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
        });
    });

  });


req.on("error", function(err) {
        console.log(`problem with request: ${err.message}`);
        });
req.end();
```

But ES is returning ALL the records (like if I was hitting the _all field), not just the hits for the query I'm passing. It's like if the request body is being ignored.

I've also tried to pass it by saving the query in a variable, and the simply put in in the json key:

```
json: query
```

But the result is the same. If I enclose the json with single quotes, I get the "unexpected token" error when trying to run the app, so I'm lost on what to do to succesfully pass a query to Node.js with the HTTP module :S.

**EDIT:**

The solution is to pass the query (JSON stringified) in the request.write method:

```
req.write(query);
```

The whole request should look like this:

```
var query = JSON.stringify({
          "query": {
            "multi_match" : {
              "query":    "this is a test", 
                "fields": [ "subject", "message" ] 
            }
          }
        });

var options = {
  hostname: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 9200,
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/twitter/tweet/_search?pretty',
  headers: {
    'content-length': Buffer.byteLength(query),
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (response) {
var responseBody = "";
    response.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        responseBody += chunk;
    });

    response.on("end", function() {
        fs.writeFile("responseBody.json", responseBody, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
        });
    });

  });


req.on("error", function(err) {
        console.log(`problem with request: ${err.message}`);
        });
req.write(query);
req.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

So the GET request of the http.request won't respect the body, it will always ignore the request body. So, you should send a **POST** request if you want to send body to the elasticsearch. 
The elasticsearch handles both POST and GET call in the same manner.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. The result didn't change if I used either a GET or POST request. What I was missing was:

- Set the content-length header
- Send the request body in the req.write method